# Android Room Partial Migration Testing

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

The codebase I'm working on ([NewPipe](https://github.com/TeamNewPipe/NewPipe)) uses Android Room. It has an [`AppDatabase`](https://github.com/TeamNewPipe/NewPipe/blob/dev/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/database/AppDatabase.java) which extends [`RoomDatabase (the Android Room class)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase), a [`StreamDAO`](https://github.com/TeamNewPipe/NewPipe/blob/dev/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/database/stream/dao/StreamDAO.kt), and a [`StreamEntity`](https://github.com/TeamNewPipe/NewPipe/blob/dev/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/database/stream/model/StreamEntity.kt). I added a column to `StreamEntity`, and I incremented the `@Database` version from `3` to `4`. I also added a `Migration` from `3` to `4`.

The problem is there was previously [a test](https://github.com/TeamNewPipe/NewPipe/blob/a536311d56c95af25e527bec0404ddf7b828dfcb/app/src/androidTest/java/org/schabi/newpipe/database/AppDatabaseTest.kt#L40) testing the Migration from version `2` to `3`. When I try to run the test, I get the error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: A migration from 3 to 4 was required but not found. Please provide the necessary Migration path via RoomDatabase.Builder.addMigration(Migration ...) or allow for destructive migrations via one of the RoomDatabase.Builder.fallbackToDestructiveMigration* methods.`. I can fix this error by adding `.addMigrations(MIGRATION_3_4)` to [this line](https://github.com/TeamNewPipe/NewPipe/blob/a536311d56c95af25e527bec0404ddf7b828dfcb/app/src/androidTest/java/org/schabi/newpipe/database/AppDatabaseTest.kt#L130). But that then also runs the migration from version `3` to `4`, which I would like to isolate to a separate test.

The `getMigratedDatabase()` function is actually only needed in the test for data validation (in addition to the automated migration verification). I am able to get the data from the (partially) migrated database by running [`queries`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/sqlite/db/SupportSQLiteDatabase?hl=en#query(java.lang.String)) on the partially migrated database, but I can't get the data as a `StreamEntity`.

How can I test partially migrating the database as well as access the `StreamDAO` on the partially migrated database?

**Edit:**
I understand (from the Android Developers Testing Single Migrations) that `You cannot use DAO classes because they expect the latest schema.`. I can get all the data out with (kotlin):

```java
query("SELECT * FROM streams").run {
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(this)
}
```

However, I can't convert it to `StreamEntity` for easier data testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test data which only half-migrated, you would have to create a matching (legacy) DB, dao and entities (not recommended).

I think you're better off reading the separate column values and then either just examine those, or take the values and construct the SteamEntity yourself.

Something like this (Java):

```
db = helper.runMigrationsAndValidate(AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME, 3, false, MIGRATION_2_3);
Cursor cursor = db.query("SELECT * FROM " + TEST_DB + ";" );
cursor.moveToFirst();
assertEquals(expectedColumnValue, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("columnName1" )));
assertNull(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("columnName2" )));
```

Then add another test for the whole migration (to v4), there you can use your Dao methods and examine StreamEntity directly and confirm that the DAO is constructing StreamEntity properly.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to clarify there was no alternative. The maintainers of the project decided to remove the migration tests and manually test database migrations.

Comment: @ktstuff ah I understand, seems like it's out of your hands now. I'm not a testing purist myself, but in my personal opinion manual testing isn't really viable here. With 3-4 database versions this get's extremely tedious already.